# AlarmManager Bug while Resetting/Cancelling Alarm on Date and Time Change

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

I want to send data to server at some `regular` interval. So, I am using `AlarmManager` for the same. It works fine but the problem is that when I `cancel` the Alarm on `Date/Time` change. At that time Alarm fires again before getting cancelled, so that makes my application worse as an `extra` data is sent to `server` with `irregular` interval.

Here is my `BroadCastReceiver` class with `AlarmManager`.

```
 public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    AlarmManager mgr;
    PendingIntent pi;
    Intent intent;
    public static boolean flag = false;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

        if(arg1.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.TIME_SET")){
            Log.d("MyReceiver", "Time set");

            mgr = (AlarmManager) arg0.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            intent = new Intent(arg0, TestService.class);
            intent.putExtra("test", "testvalue");
            pi = PendingIntent.getService(arg0, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            if(!flag){
                mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000, 5000, pi);
                flag = true;
            }
            else{
                mgr.cancel(pi);
                pi.cancel();
                flag = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the Screen Shot with Logcat output that explains that after cancelling the Alarm it fires once more time just after cancelling.

[image]

As you can see in the `Logcat` output `black arrow` shows where I changed that time to cancel the Alarm and `red arrow` shows that after cancelling the Alarm once again it fired just before cancelling which should not happen. So, can anyone give my idea why that is happening and what should I do to `restrict` Alarm getting fired again before cancelling.

**NOTE:- This only happens when I tried to increase date/time say from 10:00 to 11:00, works perfect when I decrease time say 10:00 to 9:00.**

Answer (score 0):

Not able to see the LogCat at my end, but looking at the code, I am not sure, how is the Service which gets invoked (TestService) gets killed  / stopped ? I think you would need to stop it somehow. Also, its not recommended to do long running tasks within the broadcast receiver.
Have you verified that you service stop event is occuring after the mgr.cancel(pi) is fired?

Comment: I am not stopping the service I am just resetting the alarm.

Comment: Try stopping the service as well, I guess.. Bcos there may be chances that service is still doing its work while the alarm manager is cancelled.

Comment: I don't think that is the case,because as I said it only happens when I am increasing the time and works fine when I decrease the time.

Answer (score 0):

Just  try with some unique code with pending intent within activity and then cancel that intent using the same code.

**setting pending intent in activity**

PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, **code**, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

**for stopping that broadcast receiver**

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), **code**, intent, 0);
          AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
          alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

Answer (score 0):

> why that is happening

First Thing is that you are using Intent Action `android.intent.action.TIME_SET` so It does mean that *Everytime any how if the System date/time gets Changed your BroadcastReceiver will ne called* Automatically.

Second you have used one `static boolean flag` in your `Receiver` class.
Now **what is happening is Whenever you change your System timings the flag toggles it's state from `false to true` and from `true to false`**.

That is what exactly happening in your code and logcat also shows the same that **everything is working as per the code written.**

So according to me there is **nothing** Wrong happening in the code and it's output.

```
what should I do to restrict Alarm getting fired again before cancelling
```

First thing as I think, you **should not use Action TIME_SET like that to toggle flag on/off** as users and developers *might not remember* for what they are *changing time either to turn FLAG On or Off,*

**Better way is** that, 
you should handle the Service yourself by an Activity and show one ToggleButton there to manage the State of the FLAG and set and cancel the PendingIntent.

**OR**
And If you want to do the task of *your service automatically then* you just simply use the `AlarmManager` and set your Alarm Triggering time and Interval there only once say time is currenttime and Interval is 50000 miliseconds..

so it will obviously call the service from now onwards after every 5mins, then *in your App you will only require one ToggelButton to indciate the Sync to ther server is On or Off* , if user Toggle it on or off then **write your AlarmManager code there in your Activity** only in the `toggleButtontb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener)` , I suppose *this is the better way* then what you are actually implementing.

Comment: I can't use ToggleButton as I don't have any GUI in my app. Also I want to use `TIME_SET` compulsory and fire a piece of code on time change.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand what need to set the receiver  for date change if your goal is only to send the data on server in some regular interval  .

> change date and time of device does not mean that your alarm wont work
>   at that time which you already  have set before those changes .`Alarmmanager` work on that given duration of time which is excluding  from local current date and time  of device .

Comment: I am consider from user perspective that If user changes the date and time.

Comment: if user will change it though your set alarm wont cancel , it remain as it is

Comment: I know that it won't cancel, but the problem is that when user changes date and time service gets called multiples times for the first time.

Comment: I don't understand what need to set the receiver for date change if your goal is only to send the data on server in some regular interval .